# Can I get more than just one key's value with JSONPath?

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

Here's a simplified (and syntactically not correct, because I stripped it) version of a JSON I'm currently dealing with:

```
{
  "data": {
    "134001": {
      "id": 134001,
      "label": "Deutsche Telekom",
      "is_active": true,
    },
    "134002": {
      "id": 134002,
      "label": "T-Mobile",
      "is_active": false,
    },
    "134004": {
      "id": 134004,
      "label": "1&1",
      "is_active": true,
    },
    "134005": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I use the JSONPath query string `$.data..[?(@.is_active==true)].label` I get all the labels of all the entries in `data` that have the key `is_active` set to `true`. That works fine (for example with the VSCode extension "JSON Path" bei Wei Junyu).
I could also get the `id` instead of the `label` when I use the query `$.data..[?(@.is_active==true)].id`. Works fine, too.

But what I *really* want is to get *both*, the `id` *and* the corresponding `label`.
The JSON contains much more details for each data entry and it's quite long. I want to extract a list of all the `(id, label)` pairs of all those dictionary items that have `is_active` set to `true`.

Is this a all possible with JSONPath alone? Or would I need other tools here? If so, which one(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll depend on what the implementation supports, but a common syntax is a comma-delimited list inside square brackets.

```
$.data..[?(@.is_active==true)]['id','label']
```

Comment: Awesome! This works indeed, at least with the implementation that's used in the VSCode extension I mentioned above in my original post.
This returns a single (flat) array that contains ids and labels in an alternating matter. 
I suppose it's not possible to create dictionaries (as array elements) that contain two key/value pairs for and id and a label, right?

Comment: No, that's not possible.  JSON Path doesn't have any mechanism for restructuring the data.  It's just a query and returns anything it finds.

Comment: That said, there may be a way with the implementation to return the _paths_ to the values it finds.  Using that, you can extrapolate which is the `id` and `label`.  My implementation at https://json-everything.net/json-path will return both.